# error al publicar a servidor remoto por credenciales en iis desde visual studio

Tags: c#, mvc, iis

no puedo publicar en servidor LAN IIS desde visual studio(c# mvc), pero todos los demás desarrolladores sí.

respuesta: se debe navegar desde visual studio a la dirección del server \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx e ir poniendo credenciales cuando las requiera.

Comment: y la pregunta cual es?

Comment: te da algún error al publicar? por FTP? Debes de dar más detalles.

Comment: Esta la pregunta y la solución, gracias por verla. 

Ya con eso he podido publicar sin problemas y logearme en el server iis desde el explorador de archivos del visual studio.